# How to make conversion of txt file more efficient?

Tags: c#, console

I'm trying to read in a txt file (csv or tab delimited) and convert each line into a Vector3 and add it to an array to then further process

My code so far works but it takes a while to read in a file. Each file being read in is between 6 mb to 25 mb

The code runs through and does what I expect it too but it seems to bottleneck somewhere in this `foreach` statement? Is there a quicker way or is it something that has to be expected?

```
String[] pntsText = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);
List<Vector3> pnts = new List<Vector3>();
Console.WriteLine("Start Building Points Array ...");
int noOfPnts = pntsText.Length;
int currentPntNo=0;
Console.CursorVisible = false;

foreach (string pntText in pntsText)
{
    currentPntNo++;
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write(noOfPnts - currentPntNo + " left to process");
    string[] splitXYZ = pntText.Split(new string[] { args[1] }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    Vector3 ve2 = new Vector3(float.Parse(splitXYZ[0]), float.Parse(splitXYZ[1]), float.Parse(splitXYZ[2]));
    pnts.Add(ve2);
}

Console.WriteLine("Points Array Complete");
```

Comment: If you are using C/C++, I would suggest you use pointers, but since you are using C#, I think you have to bear with it. Since you mentioned that you are reading 6mB to 25mB files.

Comment: Maybe read the whole file into one string and call `str.Split(new[] {',', '\n'})` to get a single array of all the vector parts. Then loop through, parsing them in 3s. This would prevent multiple calls to `Split`. Also avoid updating the console on every iteration. Maybe every 100th?

Comment: I know the issue is the time it takes to print to the console for you, but I would recommend learning how to use the [profiler built in to visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx) and you can get hard numbers on where your program is spending most of it's time

Comment: James hit the nail on the head I split the files into a big string array first rather than in each loop it is pretty much instant now!!!

Comment: @Jamo Great - I've added it as an answer below so you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the whole file into one string and call `str.Split(new[] {',', '\n'})` to get a single array of all the vector parts. Then loop through, parsing them in 3s. This would prevent multiple calls to `Split`. Also avoid updating the console on every iteration. Maybe every 100th?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is with your notification on console, You can comment them out and test if you get any better performance. I would suggest you to use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to time your program execution.

You can also try the following LINQ query to get a list of `Vector3`.

```
List<Vector3> list

 = pntsText.Select(r => new { Splitted = r.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None) })
           .Select(t => new Vector3(float.Parse(t.Splitted[0]), float.Parse(t.Splitted[1]), float.Parse(t.Splitted[2])))
           .ToList();
```

But this internally does the looping, so I am not sure if you get any performance gain from that and also you will not get the output on console during its processing.

Comment: The `Console` is extremely slow.  I would certainly start there.

Comment: I ran in to the same issue myself before and it is most defiantly the console. Just wrap the two console output lines with `if(currentPntNo % 1000 == 0) { /* Your two lines */ }` and you will likey see a speed boost. keep adding 0's to the number until you get about 1 update a second and watch your performance skyrocket.

Comment: I have removed the console printout during the processing, it was there so i knew it was actually doing something it has made a huge difference cheers

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Split methode to split your points:

```
string[] splitXYZ = pntText.Split(new string[] 
  { args[1] }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Having this in the for loop isnt really performant, since it allocates memory for the returned array object and a String object for each array element. Consider using the IndexOf combinied with Substring, im not sure how faster is it you will have to test this.

Read [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) about this issue:

> **Performance Considerations**
>
> The Split methods allocate memory for the
>   returned array object and a String object for each array element. If
>   your application requires optimal performance or if managing memory
>   allocation is critical in your application, consider using the IndexOf
>   or IndexOfAny method, and optionally the Compare method, to locate a
>   substring within a string.
>
> If you are splitting a string at a
>   separator character, use the IndexOf or IndexOfAny method to locate a
>   separator character in the string. If you are splitting a string at a
>   separator string, use the IndexOf or IndexOfAny method to locate the
>   first character of the separator string. Then use the Compare method
>   to determine whether the characters after that first character are
>   equal to the remaining characters of the separator string.

Another point is that you are creating an object (Vector) for each returned points array including 3 times the Parse part, which costs some performance too:

```
Vector3 ve2 = new Vector3(float.Parse(splitXYZ[0]), 
   float.Parse(splitXYZ[1]), float.Parse(splitXYZ[2]));
```

If this isnt really needed at this point (depends on your needs) you can keep the information in form of text or even a struct and create the Vector object once you need to process it at later point.

Hope this helps

Comment: Converting the file to the Vector3 type is the purpose of the loop It cannot be done any other way, thank you for your reply, much appreciated